# Atualizar Pagina Caso Consulta Retorne False

Tags: php, mysql

Galera, seguinte eu tenho essa consulta aqui

```
$consultapedidos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE produzido = '0'");
if(mysql_num_rows($consultapedidos)==true){
while($lnped = mysql_fetch_array($consultapedidos))
}
```

quando retorna true eu quero que ele faça a listagem dos resultados que ele encontrou, mas caso retorne false, eu quero que ele fique atualizando a pagina de 5 em 5 segundos até que encontre um registro.
Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$consultapedidos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE produzido = '0'");
if(mysql_num_rows($consultapedidos)==true){
    while($lnped = mysql_fetch_array($consultapedidos)) {
    }
} else {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/> ';
}
```

Basicamente isso, imprima a tag para atualizar a cada 5 segundos, basta implementar no seu código da melhor forma.

Espero que ajude

Abraço

Comment: Muito obrigado, não tinha pensado nesta logica ainda kkk, funcionou corretamente.